# Error: "multiple annotations found at this line"

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven

I have faced this error many times. in maven pom.xml files, spring application context files and at many other places. Most of the times the reason behind those errors were very different and trivial.Even though, in each of these cases the error thrown was the same. So what exactly is meant by this error. I mean when does the compiler/interpreter throws this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have 2 or more problems in the same line. For example:

`String k = "k;`

Two problems here:

```
- String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote.
- Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens.
```